# Lubuntu 14.04 blank screen after software update

Tags: 14.04

splash screen comes up then goes to a blank screen after updating software. How do I access my desktop?? Desperate for help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue but (with luck) this might help you.

Try calling your Terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T` and enter:

```
lxpanel
```

Otherwise, I think it may have something to do with the kernels since that's about the last update that did it for me.